# page numbering for chapters in front matter of report class

Tags: numbering, page-numbering, fancyhdr, report, pagestyle

[image: front page]

[image: certificate]

[image: Acknowledge page 1,show page num]

[image: acknowledge page2, show page num]

[image: content, hide pagenum]

[image: chap 1 page 1, hide page number]
[image: chap 1 page 2, pagenumber must be displayed]

[![chap 2 page 3, hide page number][8]][8]
[![chap 2 page 4, pagenumber must be displayed][9]][9]

What else can be done to hide first page of ToC, first page of Introduction, chapter one and chapter two? The page numbering in front matter is needed but not in first page of every chapter in main matter!

The below is a complete code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% document starts here...
\begin{document}

    %%frontmatter starts here
    \pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Main logo for the Project} \thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering
title\\
\vspace{2cm}
name\\
\vspace{2cm}
reg.no.\\
\vspace{2cm}
month\\
\vspace{2cm}
year}
\clearpage
    
\chapter*{\centering Certificate}
\lipsum[1-2]
\clearpage
    
\chapter*{\centering Acknowledge}
\lipsum[1-7]
\clearpage
    
%%Main matter starts here...
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \chapter*{thesis abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
    \lipsum[1-3]    
    \clearpage

    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
Brief note of Main content of the chapters.
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{one}
first chapter content...
\section{lispum one}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{two}
second chapter content...
\section{lipsum two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Currently your example does not compile. Please try to extend it to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) not loading files, we do not have. BTW: `report` does not really provide a frontmatter. Why not using `book`, that provides `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` (it has an option `oneside` so the `twoside default wouldn't be an argument). Using `\pagenumbering{roman}` several times is also not recommended. It usually results in several pages with the same number (printed or not).

Comment: now i added mwe. is it okay now?. all i need is to hide only the first page of toc and first of page every chapter, other than that, i need respective page numbers to be displayed as such.

Comment: Yes, much better. Thank you. Now it is more or less clear. IMHO your question is how to not print page numbers at pages starting a chapter. There are already questions about this, but I currently don't have the time to search for them. One suggestions would be to use `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\let\ps@empty\makeatother`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something consistent like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{import}% Loaded but currently not used. Note: You should not load
                   % not used packages.
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% Deactivating hyphenation with justified text is
                           % not recommended and will result in several
                           % overfull \hboxes! If you use this, you should at
                           % least also use \raggedright. But I would
                           % recommend to not deactivate hyphenation.
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty% Make page style plain the same like page style empty.
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
% document starts here...
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}% Recommended for titlepages
  \centering
  \vspace*{1cm}
  {\Huge Main logo for the Project\par}
  \vspace{2cm}
  
  title\\[2cm]
  name\\[2cm]
  reg.no.\\[2cm]
  month\\[2cm]
  year
\end{titlepage}
    
\chapter*{\centering Certificate}
\lipsum[1-2]
    
\chapter*{\centering Acknowledge}
\lipsum[1-7]
    
\chapter{thesis abstract}
\lipsum[1-3]    

\tableofcontents
    
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Brief note of Main content of the chapters.
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{one}
first chapter content...
\section{lispum one}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{two}
second chapter content...
\section{lipsum two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Title page + Certificate + first page of Acknowledge]

[image: second Acknowledge page + abstract + table of contents + first page of chapter 1]

[image: second page of chapter 1 + chapter 2 + chapter 3]

Maybe you additionally want:

```
\fancyhead[L]{}% remove the running head
```

As an alternative to

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty% Make page style plain the same like page style empty.
\makeatother
```

you could also use

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
```

A full example with inconsistent numbering of chapter start pages before the “thesis abstact”:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{import}% Loaded but currently not used. Note: You should not load
                   % not used packages.
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}% Deactivating hyphenation with justified text is
                           % not recommended and will result in several
                           % overfull \hboxes! If you use this, you should at
                           % least also use \raggedright. But I would
                           % recommend to not deactivate hyphenation.
\usepackage{chappg}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% document starts here...
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}% Recommended for titlepages
  \centering
  \vspace*{1cm}
  {\Huge Main logo for the Project\par}
  \vspace{2cm}

  title\\[2cm]
  name\\[2cm]
  reg.no.\\[2cm]
  month\\[2cm]
  year
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{\centering Certificate}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter*{\centering Acknowledge}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{thesis abstract}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}
\lipsum[1-3]    

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Brief note of Main content of the chapters.
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{one}
first chapter content...
\section{lispum one}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{two}
second chapter content...
\section{lipsum two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note: You can change the page styles of `fancyhdr` several times inside the document. See the manual for more information about commands like `\fancyhead`, `\fancyfoot` or `\fancypagestyle`. An alternative for using `fancyhdr` would be `scrlayer-scrpage`, which I know better, and which also provides a feature to define several pairs of headings page style and plain page style in the document preamble and switch from one pair to another one inside the document.

BTW: Per chapter page number is not really useful for the reader, because finding page 5-13 is not as easy as finding page 89. However, I know, that it is often used for some kind of documents.

Comment: Thank you by the way.. the solution you gave is fine, but the page number for certificate and acknowledge is disappear.. I need page numbering for that pages too!. Any other way ??

Comment: @Nandy I've added one more example to show, how to move the code to switch of the page numbers at plain page style, to get such inconsistent page numbering of chapter starting pages (IMHO one more typography mistake after using centered and not centered chapter headings in the same document, but if you want it, you should get it).